# OutOfMemeryError from take photo android in some devices

Tags: android, camera, out-of-memory

I have a problem when I take a photo with the camera in some devices and versions of Android. For example, in my Xperia U v4.0.3 my code works good but in another xperia U v2.3.3 it doesn't work...

I read a lot of about this error but I couldn't fix it...

My code to take a photo and show it:

```
public void callCamera(){
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
Uri.fromFile(photo));
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CAMERA);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_CAMERA) {


                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                try {

                    imageSelected = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                     .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    // I tried to read the image created for the camera in the Sd
                    //But I've got the same error... 
                    //imageSelected = Utils.readImageSD(this, selectedImage.getPath());

                     imageSelected = Utils.rotateImage(Utils.scaleBitmap(imageSelected, 160, 160));
                     ivImageLoad.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Utils.showToast(getApplicationContext(), R.string.errorLoad);
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }

            }

}
```

I hope somebody can help me... I don't know what can I do....

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you only want to display a 160x160 bitmap, but on this line you are reading in the whole bitmap and then later scaling it down.

```
imageSelected = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media(cr, selectedImage);
```

You can avoid ever loading the whole bitmap into memory by using [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds), and then you can scale it using [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize).

Here is some example code from the Android series on [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Uri uri,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {


    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
}
```

Then to get your 160x160 image you would just do:

```
ivImageLoad.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(selectedImage, 100, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the origin of the problem is the default Heap size.  There are ways to increase it:

For Android 2.2 or lower versions:

```
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(sizeInBytes);
```

For Android [2.3 or or higher versions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap):

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Check if the source of the problem is this, increasing the heap accordingly.